# Report with 2 Shared Data Sources in SSRS 2005

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am fairly new to SSRS and am stuck using 2005 right now. I am developing a report in a solution that has 2 Shared Data sources. I have a column in data source A that needs to be tied to a column in data source B.

I saw some stuff saying that pre-2008 has a harder time doing this, and I also saw info on sub-reports but it didn't quite seem to fit what I need. I've also tried to bring it in as a hidden parameter, but haven't had too much luck there.

Is there an easier way to do this that I am missing? Thanks for the help.

Comment: If I recall correctly, any method to implement this in 2005 will be a bit of a hack. Can you connect the data sources at the query/server level, such as linked servers? Subreports might work, where you create a specific subreport for a single cell that takes in a parameter from the first datasource. But performance could be horrible, depending on how often it's called.

Comment: I think right now we are looking at getting a linked server. It seems to be the least messy option. I just thought there may be an easier way within SSRS to bring the data together. Unfortunately 2005 looks pretty limited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linked Servers...Woot
Performance is a little slow but not terrible